Is there a "control-on-zero" CCNOT?
Is there a gate in Qiskit that inverts the target bit when the control bit is 0?
Is such a gate available in any machine?

Where does the "thanks for watching" come from? Was this added by mistake?

I meant thanks for looking at my question.

Since you also ask about availability on quantum hardware: Note that the control-on-zero is equivalent to a conventional controlled operation, but conjugated with Pauli $X$. For example:

equals

So every chip that can implement a Pauli-X and some controlled operation, will also be able to implement the "controlled-on-zero" equivalent. It also generalizes to multiple control qubits.

You can use the ctrl_state parameter. For example, the following code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.ccx(2,1,0,ctrl_state='00')

generates the following gate, which inverts $q_0$ when $q_1, q_2$ are $0$:

